# Item still shows as new after having been viewed

Tags: list

I've created a custom list in SharePoint 2010, but I believe I've missed a step somewhere.

I tested out the "add a new item" button. The item still shows as new after having been viewed.

Is there another step I need to do to ensure it doesn't continue to show new even though it's been viewed?

Answer (score 5):

Items will still be tagged as "New" even after they have been viewed.

By default in SharePoint 2010, the "New" icon will continue to be displayed for 2 days.

You can check the setting via Powershell:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://YourWebApp/"
$webApp.DaysToShowNewIndicator
```

You can change the "New" tag duration to 1 day as follows (or zero days by swapping "1" for "0" in the 2nd line below):

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://YourWebApp/"
$webApp.DaysToShowNewIndicator = 1
$webApp.Update()
```

Code borrowed from [this post](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Change-Settings-for-e2809cNewe2809d-Icon-in-SharePoint-2010-using-PowerShell.aspx).